# How to use facet_trelliscope when ggplot has multiple layers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `facet_trelliscope` from the `trelliscopejs` package for data visualisation. It works fine when my ggplot has one layer. But if I introduce a second layer it doesn't facet correctly. Example:

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(trelliscopejs)    

# Basic stat summary table using iris
stat_sum <-
  iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(l_mean = mean(Sepal.Length))

#Standard ggplot with facet_wrap 
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(data = stat_sum, aes(xintercept = l_mean)) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image: ggplot]

```
# Use facet_trelliscope. Data from stat_sum does not facet
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(data = stat_sum, aes(xintercept = l_mean)) +
  facet_trelliscope(~Species)
```

[image: trel]

I know I could manipulate a new data frame to contain the stat summary alongside the original data but I'd like not to if possible.

Comment: For anyone needing a quick fix see: https://github.com/hafen/trelliscopejs/issues/74. There is a dev branch available.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple layers work fine with trelliscopejs except for this special case where the layers have their own data. A fix has been prepared to make this case work as well.